# Why do we use field resolvers in graphql?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

So I have been following Ben Awad's 14 hr GraphQL and React series and I came across field resolvers and I have been a little confused about their use-case. I understand that field resolvers can be used to modify a certain data in the server. In this particular case, he uses it to slice the text of huge user posts, so in this context I am guessing that fetching large chunks of data is time consuming as the data grows, so field resolvers can be used to modify appropriate data to optimise the server. Am i right? Because this makes sense to me and this is how i understand it. Is there more to what they offer or is this it?

Comment: Since you can put arbitrary code into them, you can do pretty much anything you need from formating data, paging, hiding confidential info and more. But is there a concrete question on that?

Comment: @Alejandro Right so data modification is one reason, but when you say formatting data, does it mean that if I shorten a large paragraph, the server is more optimised? Because a query would still fetch that large text from the database before we format it right?

Comment: It greatly depends on your DB and most important what do you want to optimize for, memory usage, CPU cycles, network bandwidth or anything else. Not even all code is related to optimization at all. Do you have a **concrete** case you can share to analyze. In its current form, where just talking about very abstract things.

Comment: @Alejandro Not really I just wanted to understand the usage of it because there was not enough information in the documentation. Thank you so much for taking the time it definitely helped.